# Latest Partition Key entry in DynamoDB

Tags: mysql, amazon-dynamodb

so to explain my use case and where I am getting stuck:

I am replicating a Mysql DB to a DynamoDB instance. 
Once in DynamoDB the table looks like this:

[dynamo table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE6sN.png)

The Partition key is record_index with a sort key of meterId.

What I am looking to do is tune my API that queries the Mysql DB and writes to the DynamoDB:

Query DynamoDB for last written record_index (highest number, as it is incremental in the Mysql DB), use that record_index result as the starting point to query the Mysql DB and then write the results to the DynamoDB table.

Effectively I am trying to create an API that only writes incremental data.

I have googled and googled and cannot find a scan or query that will result in what I need.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new record in your table, include an attribute (e.g. "my_attr") that always has the same value (e.g. "constant").

Create a secondary index where `my_attr` is the primary key and `record_index` is the sort key. Then query the secondary index by my_attr='constant', limiting to one result in descending order. The item returned will have your last `record_index`.

Beware that this would create what is called a hot partition. If you need high throughput from this query or to insert/update data in the main table, this design might be a problem.

See more: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html